# Как найти количество итераций при наихудшем сценарии бинарного поиска?

Tags: алгоритм

Подскажите как найти количество итераций при наихудшем сценарии бинарного поиска. Если я правильно понимаю, то log(n):

```
log(8) = 3
```

т.е. в массиве из 8 *(=степень двойки)* эл-в понадобится максимум 3 итерации.
Если длина 5, 6, или 7, например, то сколько тогда максимально итераций?

Comment: Ну как бы очевидно - RoundUp(LOG(N)). Вот только в наихудшем случае (когда неизвестно точно, присутствует ли элемент в списке) для 8 элементов потребуется 4 сравнения...

Comment: количество итераций будет равно логарифму n по основанию двух, в массивах от 4 до 7 включительно будет две итерации

Comment: другими словами, делите ваше N на 2 до тех пор, пока не останется один элемент - так и узнаете количество итераций.

Comment: Если под наихудшим сценарием рассматривать наихудшую реализацию, то... :)